# Target a blank <input> element - only has type attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, input, react-testing-library

How can one use React Testing Library to target a blank `<input>` element that only has a `type` attribute?

For example I have my input that will be dynamically filled with attributes etc, similar to the label around it:

```
<label htmlFor={labelInput}>
    {labelText}
</label>

<input
    type="text"
    id={labelInput}
    name={labelInput}
    ...
/>
```

but while I am not passing anything to it, it will look like:

```
<input type="text" />
```

I have been reading that I can use `getByRole('input')` or `getByRole('textbox')` to target this as it has the `type="text"` attribute, but I can't seem to get this to work properly when asserting that other attributes aren't present.

For example, I can't get it to see that I am performing user actions to type text into the input...

```
const input = getByRole('textbox');
userEvent.type(input, 'some-text');

expect(input).toHaveAttribute('value', 'some-text');
```

This test returns:

```
expect(element).toHaveAttribute("value", "some-text") // element.getAttribute("value") === "some-text"

Expected the element to have attribute:
   value="some-text"
Received:
   null

  24 | 
> 25 |         expect(input).toHaveAttribute('value', 'some-text');
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears after a bit more digging that we shouldn't be using `.toHaveAttribute('value'...` but instead can directly query the `value` property of the `input` variable defined and found.

Performing the following test **PASSES**

```
expect(input.value).toBe('some-text');
```

---

As @MaxLarionov so kindly pointed out:

> Be aware that in expect(input.value).toBe('some-text'); you are assessing that the input DOM node has a value property set to some-text. It does not assess the attribute setting. For an attribute you could use native JS:

```
expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('some-text');
```

Comment: Yes, but be aware that in `expect(input.value).toBe('some-text');` you are assessing that the `input` DOM node has a `value` property set to `some-text`. It does not assess the attribute setting.

For an attribute you could use native JS: 
`expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('some-text');`